# htaccess redirect with questionmark

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to redirect `/search?q=vehicles` to `/search.php?q=vehicles` through .htaccess.

I am not an expert on .htaccess. I tried with some code, but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search$ /search.php
```

The query string is [passed through unchanged](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).